# Cuda Can't split class to header and implementation

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cuda

I have next files

Kernel.cu

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h> 
#include <device_launch_parameters.h> 
#include <texture_fetch_functions.h> 
#include <builtin_types.h> 
#include <vector_functions.h> 
#include <float.h>
#include "Book.cuh"

extern "C" __global__ void Custom2(double *data, double *c)
{

    int i = threadIdx.x;
    Book *book=new Book(data);
}
```

Book.cuh:

```
#pragma once
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
class Book
{
private:

public:

    __device__ Book::Book(double *data)
    {
    }

    __device__ double* Book::operator[] (const int index)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

};
```

These files compiles without any issue.
But now I want to split declaration and implementation to two files .cu and .cuh

so instead of Book.cuh file I will have two files

Book.cuh

```
#pragma once
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
class Book
{
public:
    __device__ Book(double *data);
    __device__ double* operator[] (const int index);
};
```

Book.cu

```
#pragma once
#include "Book.cuh"
__device__ Book::Book(double *data) 
{
}

__device__  double* Book::operator[] (const int index) 
{
    return nullptr;
}
```

and now my project doesn't compile

here is error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 8.0.targets(689,9): error MSB3721: The command ""D:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 --use-local-env --cl-version 2015 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"  -I"D:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\include" -I"D:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 -cubin -cudart static  -o X:\Projects\CudaTest\CudaTest\\kernel.ptx "X:\Projects\CudaTest\Cuda\kernel.cu"" exited with code 255.
```

Cuda Compiler settings

NVCC Compile Type: Generate .cubin file (-cubin)

My enviroment:

Windows 10 x64

Cuda 8.0

Video card: Geforce GTX 660M

I am a C# developer, and have no experience with C++ or Cuda before, I am not sure is this Cuda specific issue or it is just my almost zero knowledge of C++. Probably my issue is easy to fix, but I already spent few hours without any progress.

Comment: You haven't actually shown the error produced by nvcc

Answer (score 1):

This issue is cuda specific.
In short solution is to set Generate Relocatable Device code to -  Yes (-rdc=true)

and here is long answer:
https://devblogs.nvidia.com/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/